# Reading controls in a panel

Tags: c#

I have the following code to read all the items of some checkedlistbox objects in a panel. There are also some other controls such as labels in this panel.After reading some items correctly,I am featuring an error. Can you please help me how to correct the code:
Thanks a lot in advanced.

```
    foreach (CheckedListBox chb in PanelControls.Controls)
    {
        foreach (var itm in chb.Items)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(itm.ToString());
        }
    }
```

error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
PanelControls.Controls.OfType<CheckedListBox>()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the current control is actually a `CheckListBox`.

Something like this would suffice:

```
foreach (Control c in PanelControls.Controls) 
{ 
  if (c is CheckListBox) 
  { 
   // Do your actions
  }
}
```

Or something likes this might help you as well:

```
foreach (var control in PanelControls.Controls.OfType<CheckListBox>())
{
   ...
}
```

You are now only looping through controls that are actually a `CheckListBox`.